# Trying to make a UITableView scroll programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UITableView` that contains a `UIImageView` that scrolls up/down based on two buttons that the user presses.

The `UITableView` has a visible area on the screen that does not display all of the rows in the table.

My `UIImageView` goes up/down one row at a time, but unfortunately goes off screen when it goes to a row that isn't visible to the user.

What I would like to do is have the table automatically scroll up/down by one row, each time the user moves the `UIImageView` up/down one row that is off screen.

Eventually, once the user reaches the end of the list, if the user is at the very top of the table, then I have the `UIImageView` move to the very bottom of the `UITableView` (i.e. moves to the very last row), which would mean that the table should scroll up and display the very last row in the table.

The reverse should also be true (i.e. if the `UIImageView` is at the very bottom of the list, then pressing the down button should take the user to the very top of the table, and the table should automatically scroll to the very beginning of the list, displaying the first row in the table to the user).

Here is my code that moves the `UIImageView` in the `UITableView`:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    if([sender tag] == 1){

        if (_index.row == 0) {

            _index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[_tableData count] - 1 inSection:_index.section];
            //here is my code that controls the scrolling of the table
            [_table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:_index atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

        }

        else
            _index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_index.row - 1 inSection:_index.section];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
            CGRect rect = [self.view convertRect:[_table rectForRowAtIndexPath:_index] fromView:_table];

            CGFloat floatx = _imageView.frame.origin.x - rect.origin.x;
            _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + floatx, rect.origin.y, _imageView.frame.size.width, _imageView.frame.size.height);
        }];

    }

    else if([sender tag] == 2){

        if (_index.row + 1 == [_tableData count]) {

            _index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:_index.section];
            //here is my code that controls the scrolling of the table
            [_table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:_index atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

        }

         else
             _index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_index.row + 1 inSection:_index.section];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
            CGRect rect = [self.view convertRect:[_table rectForRowAtIndexPath:_index] fromView:_table];

            CGFloat floatx = _imageView.frame.origin.x - rect.origin.x;
            _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + floatx, rect.origin.y, _imageView.frame.size.width, _imageView.frame.size.height);
        }];

    }

}
```

Can anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand why you are changing the x value and not just the y value. 
For the y value, is your image view a subview of the tableview (scrollview) or of the view containing it?

Comment: I'm simply changing the x value so that the UIImageView moves over to the left a little (this I have done on purpose).  The height is correct, which is why I am not changing the y value.

Comment: well your code is only scrolling when getting to the top or bottom of the table view. If you want it to scroll along with the image view you have to scroll to row in your animation blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I think this is the approach I need to take in order to get this working.  Can you post your comment as a solution?